# Creating a custom table of orders in WooCommerce - taking ages to loop through orders

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, woocommerce, orders

I am creating a section of my WooCommerce website where my corporate clients can log on and see which of their employees have made orders.

In order to do this, I'm planning to use a **`WP_List_Table`** which will be populated by some data.

However, I am struggling to create my data array because of the size of our posts table and our order-base (c. 10000 orders), it takes ages to run through the loop.

Here is my code to create a basic array of email addresses - but Wordpress throws a fatal error after 30 seconds.

Does anyone have an idea of how I can do this in a way which will work better? Thoughts much appreciated.

```
// Set the parameters for a orders

$customer_orders = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
    'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() ),
) );


// Pull a list of order IDs

$orderids = [];
foreach ($customer_orders as $customer_order) {
    $orderids[] = $customer_order->ID;
}

// Create a list of orders
$orders = [];
foreach ($orderids as $orderid) {
    $order = wc_get_order($orderid);
    $order_company = $order->get_billing_company();

    if($order_company = 'Corporate Client Name') {
         $orders[] = $order->get_billing_email();
    }
}

print_r($orders);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should better use a custom SQL query, **filtered directly** by 'Corporate Client Name' billing company name. This will avoid to go through your 5000 orders. Here is that code:

```
// Filtering by a company from the beginning
$order_company = 'Corporate Client Name';

global $wpdb;

$table_postmeta = $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta";

// 1. First SQL query the order IDs related to 'Corporate Client Name'
$results = $wpdb->get_col( "
    SELECT post_id
    FROM $table_postmeta
    WHERE $table_postmeta.meta_key LIKE '_billing_company'
    AND $table_postmeta.meta_value = '$order_company'
" );

// Convert the array of IDs in a coma separated string
$orders_str = implode(',', $results);

// 2. Second SQL query get the emails from order IDs related to 'Corporate Client Name'
$emails = $wpdb->get_col( "
    SELECT meta_value
    FROM $table_postmeta
    WHERE $table_postmeta.meta_key LIKE '_billing_email'
    AND $table_postmeta.post_id IN ($orders_str)
" );


// Testing output
print_r( $emails );
```

This code is tested and works

Comment: You are a gent Loic. I'll have a go tomorrow (it is getting late here) and see how I get on. Thank you.

Comment: Hiya Loic, Sorry for the slow response. I have been away from my computer all weekend. The above works brilliantly - apart from where you've written  `!= '$order_company'` I assumed you mean `= '$order_company'`? Thank you so much. This is my first foray into SQL so an exciting one!